Concerning an alleged Aquinas quote on anger
There is a meme circulating where the statement

He who is not angry when there is just cause for anger is immoral. Why? Because anger looks to the good of justice. And if you can live amid injustice without anger, you are immoral as well as unjust.

is attributed to Thomas Aquinas.
Aquinas treats of anger in Summa Theologiæ II-II q. 158, but the quote does not seem to appear there.
Is the quote in the meme attributable to Thomas Aquinas, or not?

I do see a similar questions in Reddit and other places, but it doesn't sound like something Aquinas would say though.  Still looking for the source.  It is possibly part of the Objection that he would refute (since plenty of objections consist of Patristic quotes).  This blog article suggest to me that it maybe John Chrysostom.  Good searchable bilingual corpus of Aquinas writings here.  Good question!

Remember that the Summa is his most famous work, but he wrote a lot more, much of which hasn't been translated entirely.

@GratefulDisciple Ray MacGovern, who you as well linked to, expresses a point of view similar to the one I linked to in the question from 25:38 to 26:30 in the following video: https://www.youtube.com/live/aHfNus7C9nk?si=musf143g4wtxXvTi.

@eques Indeed! Aquinas was one of the most prolific philosophy authors, and it is quite possible that he wrote something which explains the attribution in another text than the Summa.

Summa Theologiæ II-II q. 158 a. 8 s.c.:

On the contrary, Chrysostom* says:

He who is not angry, whereas he has cause to be, sins. For unreasonable patience is the hotbed of many vices, it fosters negligence, and incites not only the wicked but even the good to do wrong.
Sed contra est quod Chrysostomus dicit, super Matth., qui cum causa non irascitur, peccat. Patientia enim irrationabilis vitia seminat, negligentiam nutrit, et non solum malos, sed etiam bonos invitat ad malum.


*Feser, By Man Shall His Blood Be Shed, ch. 4 n. 56:

Aquinas is citing the work Opus Imperfectum or Incomplete Commentary on Matthew, which, according to the translator of the modern edition, “was wrongly ascribed for centuries to John Chrysostom”. The true author is unknown. See Thomas C. Oden, ed., Incomplete Commentary on Matthew, trans. James A. Kellerman (Downers Grove, Ill.: IVP Academic, 2010), 1:xvii.


Thanks. I saw the text you quote in your first paragraph. It is not by Aquinas, nor does it conform to the meme I quoted. It is interesting that the quote is now taken by specialists to have been misattributed to John Chrysostom.
